Installing from instant app fails with white screen
I use this code from my instant app.
I expected that I will get some functional prompt that will install the app.
But it shows some white dialog that is thin and tall but not functional
I have no idea how to proceed, can you share your experience how do you install the full version from instant app?
I found the code at this documentation, and I adjusted for my package etc.
https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#test-publish-internal-test-track
 private fun showInstallPrompt() {
        val postInstall = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
                .setPackage(your-installed-experience-package-name)

        // The request code is passed to startActivityForResult().
        InstantApps.showInstallPrompt(this@MyInstantExperienceActivity,
                postInstall, request-code, /* referrer= */ null)
    }



your app is live?

Yes it is live. But hmm, when you asked this, maybe I could have issue with the versions. The all is live with internal testing version 121 and public with 110. Maybe this install gets confused because internal is further from the public. Hmm, I will try this

yes definitely first open your internal and do a clear catch and then try with QR maybe it's work.

Thanks a lot, the problem was with versioning/caching etc. I took coffee (enough time have passed) and the version have synced in the internal track. I guess it is not so immediate as I initially thought. It works - the problem was I had 120 instead of 121. The 121 was not synced yet
